# Select specific element by jQuery and manipulate in socket.io

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am a totally newbie in node.js and socket.io. I want to inplement a simple function that when a socket click the button, the background color of that button will toggle to blue.

This is my client html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
      .blue {
          background: blue;
      }
  </style>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var socket = io();
        $("button").click(function(){
            socket.emit("click button");
            return false;
        });
        socket.on("click button", function(){
            $("button").toggleClass("blue");
        });
    });
    </script>
  <body>
    <button>Click me to change</button>
    <br>
    <button>Don't change me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my server.js file:

```
var express = require("express"),
app     = express(),
server  = require("http").createServer(app),
io      = require("socket.io").listen(server);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("click button", function(){
        io.emit("click button");
    })
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("The server is now starting......");
});
```

Of course this code can not work since it toggled all buttons when clicked one button. But I want to know what is the correct way that only toggle the button which is clicked?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Add `id`s to your buttons and send the id of the button that got clicked (`$(this).attr('id')`) to your io.socket. In the subscribe method of your socket (`socket.on()`) read the id from the event/payload and use it to only call `toggleClass` for the respective button by using the id in the jQuery selector (implementing this is left to the question author as an exercise )

Comment: Thank you Capricorn! Very helpful suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `this` keyword to select the clicked element, eg.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  socket.emit("click button");
  $(this).toggleClass("blue");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This would only trigger the background of the button on the current website. If I got the question right he want's to send the toggle-trigger via the io socket, causing all buttons on potential other browser windows to also change

Comment: Hmm, you could be right. The OP was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Yes. I want to send the toggle via the socket. The original question is not very clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MingshuShi no problem, then I suggest you look at Capricorn's comment ;)